# Oracle SQL: Compare Date Ranges and get the dates of the same day

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

I have different events:

[image]

If more than 2 of them take place in one day, I would like to know which ones and how many that are.
How do I build the SQL command?

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

More than 2 events on the same day.

Comment: Post your sample data and expected output as plain text, not images.

Comment: how event ID 181 is expected in the outcome ? Date_from and Data_until are not 27..please explain

Comment: please give samples

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    WITH calendar
     AS (    SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE - LEVEL ) AS cal_day
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < 30)
  SELECT calendar.cal_day,
         COUNT( e.event_id ) AS number_of_events,
         LISTAGG( e.event_id, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.date_from)
            AS events
    FROM calendar, event e
   WHERE calendar.cal_day BETWEEN e.date_from AND e.date_until
GROUP BY calendar.cal_day
  HAVING COUNT( e.event_id ) > 1;
```

You can always change number in `CONNECT BY LEVEL < :n` or materialize calendar as a table.

Answer (score 0):

sample input:

```
create table ns_123(a int,b date,c date);

insert into ns_123 values(179,'27-sep-2018','27-sep-2018');

insert into ns_123 values(181,'26-sep-2018','28-sep-2018');

insert into ns_123 values(180,'27-sep-2018','27-sep-2018');

select * from ns_123;

select distinct n1.a from  ns_123 n1,ns_123 n2 where  (n1.b-n2.b)>=(n1.c-n2.c);
```

sample output:

```
179
180
181
```